# MOSS 2007 Links List Changing Automatically

Tags: 2007, content-type

Whenever I post a link to an external site, for some reason SharePoint changes the domain name to the server domain name. E.g. If I post google.com/new-url, it will change it to mysite.com/new-url.

I've looked at the Content Type, the list, re-created the list several times - nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you include the protocol part of the url e.g. http :// <your url>

Comment: With or without the protocol does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked for an attached event receiver? maybe itemadding event receiver that is attached on the list/content type?
You can use the SharePoint Utility Pack - http://spstipsutilitypack.codeplex.com/ - to check whether you have an event receiver attached or not...